# maps and core data swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

my program works as follow, once the program been run a tableview with one location on it will appear. once the location been clicked it moves to another controller which shows the location on the map. to add a new place to the tableview just press for 2 seconds on a place on the map, then the place will be added to the tableview.

I am trying to include core data to save the locations. and I have two problems.

first one. I don't know exactly where to call the loadLocations() function.
Secondly, when I call   loadLocations() function I get an error ( Could not cast value of type 'maps.Location' (0x6000018f3ea0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1025c7818). ) for line (  places = try context.fetch(request) as! [Dictionary] ) inside the function.

my codes:
viewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!


@objc func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   let newPlace = Location(context: context)


    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        print("===\nLong Press\n===")
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)
        let newCoordinate = self.map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)
        print(newCoordinate)
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)
        var title = ""
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                    if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                        title += placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "
                    }
                    if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                        title += placemark.thoroughfare!
                    }
                } }
            if title == "" {
                title = "Added \(NSDate())"
            }
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
            annotation.title = title
            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            newPlace.location = title
            newPlace.latitude = String(newCoordinate.latitude)
            newPlace.longitude = String(newCoordinate.longitude)
            appDelegate.saveContext()
            places.append(["name":title, "lat": String(newCoordinate.latitude), "lon":String(newCoordinate.longitude)])


        }) }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard currentPlace != -1 else { return }
    guard places.count > currentPlace else { return }
    guard let name = places[currentPlace]["name"] else { return }
    guard let lat = places[currentPlace]["lat"] else { return }
    guard let lon = places[currentPlace]["lon"] else { return }
    guard let latitude = Double(lat) else { return }
    guard let longitude = Double(lon) else { return }
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.008, longitudeDelta: 0.008)
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    annotation.title = name
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)


    print(currentPlace)

    let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.longpress(gestureRecognizer:)))
    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2
    map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)
}
```

}

PlacesViewController:

```
         @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return places.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default,reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if places[indexPath.row]["name"] != nil {
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]


    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    currentPlace = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "to Map", sender: nil)
}

       override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if places.count == 1 && places[0].count == 0 {
        places.remove(at: 0)
        places.append(["name":"Ashton Building", "lat": "53.406566", "lon": "-2.966531"])
    }

     currentPlace = -1
     loadLocations()
     table.reloadData()

}


func loadLocations (){

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Location")

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do{
        places = try context.fetch(request) as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
        table.reloadData()
    }catch{

    }

}
```

Comment: Regarding the error: A standard `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` returns `[NSFetchRequestResult]` not an array of dictionaries. If you change the request to `NSFetchRequest<Location>(entityName: "Location")` you'll get `[Location]` without type cast

Comment: still didn't work  @vadian

Comment: I know, but it fixes the error.

Answer (score 0):

The below code shows the map with in annotation in center

```
guard let name = places[currentPlace]["name"] else { return }
guard let lat = places[currentPlace]["lat"] else { return }
guard let lon = places[currentPlace]["lon"] else { return }
guard let latitude = Double(lat) else { return }
guard let longitude = Double(lon) else { return }
//let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.008, longitudeDelta: 0.008)
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
//let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
//self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = coordinate
annotation.title = name
self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
self.map.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
```